# How could I store the variables better?

Tags: javascript, python, html, geolocation

Here is my group's project: https://github.com/stuycs-ml7-projects/YAN-SHAN-PHAN-WU

We're working on app (a website) that can store messages at locations using GPS. Messages can only be accessed and stored at their specific coordinates.

I'll go through what I have.

HTML initializes the variables

```
<input type="hidden" id="Latitude" name="Latitude">
<input type="hidden" id="Longitude" name="Longitude">
```

I use a document.ready function to call getLocation() which stores them in the hidden fields.

```
function getLocation()
  {if (navigator.geolocation)
    {    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);     }
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
      document.getElementById("Latitude")  =  position.coords.latitude;
      document.getElementById("Longitude") =  position.coords.longitude;
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
   getLocation();
});
```

If I press a button, it will request the data in app.py

```
Latitude = request.form['Latitude']
Longitude = request.form['Longitude']
```

Then find all the messages at the location

```
messages = database.returnMessagesinRange(Latitude,Longitude)
            return render_template('SCAN.html',messages=messages,
                Latitude =   Latitude, Longitude = Longitude)
```

**Somewhere along the line, I lose the coordinates and end up with blank variables. Any ideas how to fix, or possibly a shortcut to avoid all the trouble?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a quick guess, but try replacing document.getElementById("Latitude") = ... with document.getElementById("Latitude").value = ...

Comment: a couple more bugs, but this really helped, I would never think to look for this

Comment: Glad it helped! While learning this stuff one thing that really worked for me was the Gecko Dom reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference). It's a bit dense but pretty exhaustive.